# Search by modified date shows wrong results

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, search, search-results

I have a strange issue: if I search for documents that have not been modified for 2 years, I will still find documents that have been modified in 2014. Obviously, this is unexpected and unwanted.

I've used advanced search for this, resulting in the following query: Write<=1-1-2012

Any ideas what may cause this behavior?
Thank you for your help!

Edit:
I'm using sharepoint 2010 by the way...

Comment: I think you need to add the date in this format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I just tried that, and unfortunately ended up with the same (wrong) search results...

Comment: I do not recognize the Managed Property `Write`, shoud you not use `Modified`?

Comment: You mean Modified<=2012-1-1? The first hit is a document created in 2013, so this isn't working as expected either :-/

Comment: You should still use correct query format

Comment: Modified<=2012-01-01T23:00:00Z - is this the correct query format? It has 0 results (using 2015 instead of 2012 also has 0 results). Again, thank you for your quick reply!

Comment: My answers are probably only valid for 2013, I see now you use 2010

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the query as

```
Write<="1/1/2012"
```

Here is a good [reference](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/07/20/some-handy-keywords-you-might-find-useful-in-sharepoint-enterprise-search.aspx) for search keywords for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the reference! Unfortunately, it still shows the wrong search results... :-/

Comment: did you try to directly type this into the default search box instead of doing it into the advanced search ?

Comment: Yes I did, any other ideas?

Comment: I just tested this in my environment and it works for me. Make sure you do not have any spaces in the query and put the date in quotes. Also, might sound naive, but are you sure there are documents available for the criteria you are searching on ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Most results in the search result match what I'm looking for, but quite a few do not. I guess the search query is correct, so that would suggest something underwater is broke..?

Answer (score 0):

I guess date/time should be UTC in ISO formatted.

Date *YYYY-MM-DD*:

**2017-06-15**

Date with time *YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ*:

**2017-06-15T18:30:00Z**